# A cyclic subsemigroup of a semigroup S that is a group

Tags: semigroups

I came across this problem while reading some lectures about semigroups here [Lecture Notes on Semigroups by Tero Harju](http://users.utu.fi/harju/semigroups/semigroups.pdf). Page $10$. He named it a nontrivial exercise.

Let $r$ be the index and $p$ the period of an element $x\in S,$ a semigroup. Then

$$K_{x}=\{ {x^{r},x^{r+1},...x^{r+p-1} } \}$$

is a subgroup of S, i.e a subsemigroup that is a group.

I know I have to show that

1. $K_{x}$ is closed under the operation in S.
2. $K_{x}$ has identity.
3. For any element of $K_{x}$ there exist its inverse for which their product is also in $K_{x}$.

Please I need a hint to help me solve the above problem.

Comment: I am sorry for chaos confused by my earlier edits. Could you perhaps give a link to the text you're reading or at least to have a look whether the definition of _period_ and _index_ your text is using is the same as in my answer?

Comment: Here is the link. It is lemma 1.5 page 10 users.utu.fi/harju/semigroups/semigroups.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cyclic semigroups are best seen on a graph. I will show you an example but first a bit of an introduction. The name "cyclic" is a bit misleading, which is why some authors (most prominently Howie) call those semigroups "monogenic" instead. The name is misleading because, unlike cyclic groups, cyclic semigroups do not look like circles -- unless they're actually cyclic groups! However, they do have a circle in them, and the circle is exactly the cyclic subgroup you are asking about.

There exists a cyclic semigroup of every period and index. Indeed, let's take the element

$a_{m,r}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & ... & m & m+1 & ... & m+r-1 & m+r \\ 2 & 3 & 4 & ... & m+1 & m+2 & ... & m+r & m+1 \end{pmatrix}$

in the semigroup $\mathcal{T}_{m+r}$ of all functions from an $(m+r)-$element set into itself, for some positive integers $m,\,r.$ The second row in this matrix tells us what is ascribed to the element above it. The element $a_{m,r}$ generates the cyclic semigroup of index $m$ and period $r.$

So let's see what it looks like for $m=4$ and $r=8.$ We take

$a=a_{4,8}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\ 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 5  \end{pmatrix}.$

The graph of this semigroup looks like this

[image: cyclic semigroup]

The cycle in the graph is the representation of the cyclic subgroup generated by a certain element, one of $a^4, a^5, a^6, a^7, a^8, a^9, a^{10}, a^{11}.$

Why is it a subgroup? Let's find out whether it has an identity element $e$. An identity element must be idempotent, that is $e^2$ must be equal to $e.$ Let's see. We get the equation

$(a^{4+k})^2=a^{4+k}$ for $k\in\{0,1,...,7\}.$

It's not difficult too see from the picture that it's equivalent to

$2(4+k)\equiv 4+k \mod 8;$

$k\equiv -4 \mod 8.$

So $k=4$ and we get that $a^{4+4}=a^{8}$ is the only idempotent contained in the cycle. It is now a matter of a simple check to see that it is indeed an identity element in $\{a^4,...,a^{11}\}.$

We now need to show that for every $k\in \{0,...,7\}$ there is $l\in\{0,...7\},$ such that

$a^{4+k}a^{4+l}=a^8.$

Again, this is equivalent to

$4+k+4+l\equiv 8 \mod 8;$

$l \equiv -k \mod 8.$

Of course there is a solution of this congruence in the set $\{0,...,7\}.$ We have a group, indeed!

Now, why is it cyclic? We need to find a generator. We need a number $g\in\{0,...,7\}$ such that for any $k\in\{0,...,7\}$ there exists $l\in\{0,...,7\},$ such that

$(a^{4+g})^l=a^{4+k}.$

Notice that the solution of the congruence

$4+g\equiv 1 \mod 8,$

which obviously exists in the set $\{0,...,7\},$ works.

We are done with the example. Extending this to a general case shouldn't be very difficult.

Comment: I think the general case is not trivial.

Comment: Not trivial perhaps, but you only need to imitate the example. If you have problems, please edit your question to show what you have done and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly we have:

$$r'=\min \{b; x^a=x^b\text{ for some }b\ne a\}$$

The number $r$ is the unique number $r<r'$ fulfilling $x^r=x^{r'}$. The number $p$ is defined by $p=r'-r$.

Let us first show that for $a,b\ge r$ the following holds
$$x^a=x^b \Leftrightarrow a\equiv b \pmod p$$

*Proof.* Since $x^{r+p}=x^r$, we have $x^{a+kp}=x^a$ for any $a\ge r$, $k\ge 0$.

To show the reverse implication, it suffices to rewrite $a=r+q_1p+r_1$ and $b=r+q_2p+r_2$ for $0\le r_1,r_2<p$ (by long division). We get $x^{r+r_1}=x^{r+r_2}$ and the definition of $p$, $r'$ and $r$ implies $r_1=r_2$, which means that $a$ and $b$  are congruent.

Showing the closedness of $K_x$ using the above condition should be easy. This also shows that $K_x$ is a cancellative. Every finite cancellative semigroup is a group.

---

You can find a proof of the fact you were asking about e.g. in the book Commutative semigroup rings By Robert W. Gilmer as [Theorem 2.1](http://books.google.com/books?id=sOPNfkp-Le8C&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q&f=false). I found this book by searching for [semigroup element period](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&pwst=1&q=semigroup+element+period&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbo=u&tbm=bks). (Which I did because the notion of period of an element was new to me.)